# Windows 10 laptop cannot connect with Linux Samba server (SMBv3)

Tags: windows-10, services, smb2

I've set up a Samba share on a Ubuntu 20.04 server using `SMBv3`, disabling `SMBv1`. Several Windows 10 laptops can connect to this server, but one refuses, and I don't see *anything* in the Samba logs with `loglevel` increased (it should at least show a connection attempt and a specific file for this laptop - neither is there).

- It seems like the problem is on the laptop side; I've looked at the logs, but am not 100% what to look for - it seems like the Workstation service should be running, and I can't start it; `Netlogon` and `Remote Desktop Configuration` services can't be started either (these services seem dependent on each other - workstation depends on `Netlogon` and `Remote Desktop Configuration` and both depend on Workstation). 
  How can I start any of them?

I've tried:

- changing ownership of several registry keys to `SYSTEM` and `Administrators`, but after changing this and restarting, other keys came up; is this an endless road? 
  CLSID: `{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}` 
   APPID: `{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}`
- running Windows system repair (keeping files), but that didn't do anything and the whole repair was over in 1s
- running, with no change afterward: `sfc /scannow`

  ```
  Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
  For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
  ```

Should I reinstall this system?

Comment: You can check the system if SMBv3 is activated: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/storage/file-server/troubleshoot/detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-v2-v3#windows-81-and-windows-10-powershell-method

Comment: @Robert, sorry, should have mentioned that more clearly, but of course I did that. SMBv3 is activated, SMBv1 disabled.

Comment: @John, you mean I should repair by reinstalling from a USB stick, keeping the data?

Comment: Why was it even suggested to reinstall Windows to solve this problem?  Provide the log file, the files that are corrupt, likely have nothing to do with SMBv3 furthermore DISM should be used before you reinstall if you choose to take that chainsaw solution instead of the hammer solution

Comment: You do not need to re-install Windows, however `SFC /ScanNow` cannot be run on it's own and never first... the correct sequence of commands is: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → Must be connected to the internet: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` → Reboot → `SFC /ScanNow` → Reboot. If corruption is found, you should review the DISM log [`C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log`] and CBS log [`C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`] to see what was replaced _(start at the bottom of the log and work your way upwards)_

Comment: @SPRBRN Please explain what you mean by _"running Windows system repair (keeping files), but that didn't do anything and the whole repair was over in 1s"_, as that wording doesn't make sense relative to the bullet point following it since Windows system repair is `SFC`.

Comment: @John, I downloaded the tool, started it and it suggested an upgrade, which probably was a repair (reinstall of system files), and it was possible to keep all user data. This was done within a user account, not using a usb-stick. It took about 30 minutes and now samba works. If you want the points, make it an answer!

Comment: @Ramhound - the suggestion from John did work without erasing user data. I tried it, knowing that it would probably give an option to do a clean install or keep data, and it did. SMBv3 works now.

Comment: @JW0914 - thanks for the SFC correction. I'll make a note for future use. Problem is already solved by doing a system update/repair with the suggested tool.

Comment: @SPRBRN What you performed is a repair install, however it's always recommended to use `DISM` and `SFC` first, as they perform the same function, just without modifying the Registry or re-creating user profiles.